# What happens if I increment a completed achievement on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

This question is about GPGS (Google Play Game Services). Say we have three achievements like:

- Achievement A: Kill a total of 3 enemies
- Achievement B: Kill a total of 6 enemies
- Achievement C: Kill a total of 12 enemies

As they are all measured with total amount of kills, when players kill an enemy, all them three should increase. So what happens if I continue to send increments after total amount exceeds 3 for A, 6 for B, 12 for C?

Comment: Those are milestones. They don't change. Achievement A indicates player killed 3 enemies. We check the number of kills. If kills are more than the predefined threshold, award that achievement. May be use enums or bools to keep track of which achievement has been awarded already

Comment: @SanSolo I assume you red the tags, cause i didn't even know some kind of milestone-categorization existed in GPGS. Then, how can i access the total number of kills player made? And i can't use enums or bools for that kind of tracking, since the product will be an online game.

Comment: sorry didn't read the tag. With respect to google play service or game center achievements, you handle that in your code. Check if an achievement has been awarded already, if not award it. This information should be saved on device using binary files ( not player prefs)

Comment: @SanSolo Ok, checking is the solution; but this is still not answering the question: What happens if i do incerement an already awarded achievement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attempt to increment an incremental achievement beyond the number of steps defined for that achievement, nothing happens. See [the documentation for `gpg::AchievementManager::Increment`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/api/group__Managers#abd50c7ba42bef05a49abde8945271ff4) (or the same variant of the API for whatever language you prefer).